# Lost of precision using sparse matrices in matlab?

Tags: matlab, precision, sparse-matrix

I have two matrices J1 (sparse) = J2(full).

The dimension of the matrices are ~ 5200x2600

Then when I do:

```
hlm1 = (J1'*J1 + u*I)\g, I = eye(n);
```

and

```
hlm2 = (J2'*J2 + u*I)\g, I = eye(n);
```

i have after that: `norm(hlm1 - hlm12, Inf)` is `4.8625e-05` ...

That difference is my problem, is correct the way to use the matrice sparse ?.

Thx.

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example? Perhaps by constructing the sample matrix with a few commands to look roughly like your matrix or otherwise uploading a file somewhere? Otherwise it will be hard to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but I think it could be useful. I can partially reproduce this difference using some random data:

```
H1=sprand(1000,1000,.4);
g=sprand(1000,1,.5);
x=H1*g;
H2=full(H1);
x2=full(x);

g1=H1\x;
g2=H2\x2;

difference=norm(g1-g2,Inf)
errorSparse=norm(g1-g,Inf)
errorFull=norm(g2-g,Inf)
```

the norm ends up roughly O(1e-12). I think the difference is due to the method used to solve sparse system of equations. Solving the sparse system will be using sparse function, and solving the full matrix will be using a different set of functions. Naturally these functions will be different, and I think this is probably causing some differences. I can't explain why the errors are that large though.

See [the documentation for `mldivide`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) which includes some short discussion about sparse matrices as well as some methods use to solve them.

Comment: Hi, thx for you answer, with the 'mldivide' i get the same result...

About you answer, when i do:

hlm1 = (full(J1)'*full(J1) + u*I)\g

and with the same hlm2 .. I get a norm inf of 9.6..e-20 i have the same problem :( ..

Comment: Two comments: 1) `full(J1)` turns `J1` from a sparse matrix into a full matrix, so you probably want to avoid that if you need to use sparse matrices. 2) a norm of 9.6e-20 is incredibly tiny, is that a typo?

Comment: 1) Yes, but I did it to see that the problem seems more of the matrix  sparse or the function **full** than of the operation: \  
2) that little error (e-4) is problematic even e-20 my details are at that level (that error will accumulate) ....

Comment: If you worry about errors of 1E-20 on matrices of 5200x2600 you need to do all the math yourself. Numerical stability is a very tricky subject - think really, really hard about what you are trying to do, because it sounds "almost impossible". Do you know how small 1E-20 is? [If the distance to the sun is 1, then 1E-20 is 1.5 nm](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28distance+to+the+sun%29%2F1E20). That is a LOT less than a wavelength of visible light. See my point? You need to reformulate your problem so you don't care about such small differences.

Comment: In that case things are quite difficult. If you type `eps` what do you get? Most computers would returna number roughly 2e-16. This is the smallest difference between two numbers the computer can see. So if you have two numbers less that 2e-16 apart, the computer wont be able to recognise them.

Comment: Ok e-20 is when i use the full(J)*full(J) .. but not have reason to do that (i am and i want use the sparse).....